# How to inject primitive variables in Kotlin?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-lateinit

I am using Dagger2 for DI in my Android app, and using this code for injecting classes into my Activity is fine:

```
@field:[Inject ApplicationContext]
lateinit var context: Context
```

but, `lateinit` modifier is not allowed on primitive type properties in Kotlin (for instance `Boolean`), how can I do something like this?

```
@field:[Inject Named("isDemo")]
lateinit var isDemo: Boolean
```

when I remove `lateinit` from this code I get this error `Dagger does not support injection into private fields`

Comment: `@JvmField @field:[Inject Named("isDemo")] var isDemo: Boolean = false`

Comment: @Miha_x64 and where is the Inject and Named annotations?!

Comment: @Miha_x64 Thank you, it works!

Comment: @Miha_x64 please add your answer. Upvoting comments is so boring.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, you don't need `lateinit`, you can leave it as a `var`, and initialize with an arbitrary value.
Second, you must expose a field in order to allow Dagger to inject there.
So, here's the solution:

```
@JvmField // expose a field
@field:[Inject Named("isDemo")] // leave your annotatios unchanged
var isDemo: Boolean = false // set a default value
```

Comment: Maybe you should think of a `protected` true if you want to protect your property to be accessed (and changed) just in (sub-)classes - works with Dagger because this won't result in `private`

Comment: This works. Thanks. This is some mess. Hope dagger/kotlin solves this.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't work with me, but the following worked well:

```
@set:[Inject Named("isDemo")]
var isDemo: Boolean = false
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@WindRider/correct-usage-of-dagger-2-named-annotation-in-kotlin-8ab17ced6928)

Comment: For me works only accepted answer, not yours. In your case I'm getting error "Dagger does not support injection into private fields"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hilt and came across this question and also using your own qualified annotation, you can use this syntax too:

```
@Inject
@IsDemo
@JvmField 
var isDemo: Boolean = false
```